# Kivymd OneLineIconListItem shows 2 icon

Tags: python, kivymd

I have this one function where I fetch 10 songs from database and display the songs into OneLineIconListItem. My code works just fine, but the thing is, there is 2 icons showing. Why does I get 2 icons? If someone know why this happens please help me.

Below is my code and the screenshot of OneLineIconListItem with 2 icons that I get.

```
OneLineIconListItem class code:

class SongList(OneLineIconListItem):
    song = StringProperty() # to store song title


The .kv for SongList:

<SongList>:
    text: root.song
    IconLeftWidget:
        icon: "arrow-right-drop-circle"

The fetch function:

if emo_detected == "happy":
            happy_query = "SELECT SongName FROM songs_list WHERE SongCluster=1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10"
            self.cursor.execute(happy_query)
            happy_songs = self.cursor.fetchall()
            for i in happy_songs:
                rechappy = SongList()
                rechappy.song = i[0]
                self.wm.screens[3].ids['recommended_song_list'].add_widget(rechappy)

MDList where I want to put the OneLineIconListItem:

ScrollView:
     bar_width: 0
     MDList:
     id: recommended_song_list
```

[image: The screenshot of OneLineIconListItem with 2 icons that I get]

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem up until today. My issue was that in a Drop Down menu:

```
menu_items = [
            {
                "viewclass": "IconListItem",
                "text": f"{i}" if i > 9 else f"%s" % ("0" + str(i)),
                "height": dp(56),
                "on_release": lambda x=f"{i}" if i > 9 else f"%s" % ("0" + str(i)): self.set_month(x),
            } for i in range(1,13)
        ]
        self.menu_month = MDDropdownMenu(
            caller=self.ids.month_list,
            items=menu_items,
            position="center",
            width_mult=4,
        )
        self.menu_month.bind()
```

where I defined `"viewclass": "IconListItem",` in `menu_items` it turned out that I had defined the class `IconLilstItem` twice in my .kv file. i.e., The following was defined twice:

```
<IconListItem>

    IconLeftWidget:
        icon: root.icon
```

So either in your `MDList` or your `SongList` you are defining the `IconLeftWidget` twice or you are making a call to a class defining an `IconLeftWidget`.

Check your code for redundant declarations.

Hope that helps!